# Guitar Tab Book

Tags: guitar, sheet-music, tablature

I know that I should probably just use the music notation Moleskin and write out in music notation. However, sometimes I come up with chord and modal note combinations that I think sound cool, and want to jot them down quickly into a streaming tab. I have been using the music notation moleskin for this, and just use a ruler to add an extra line to the staff - turning it into a guitar tab staff. Any ideas? Actually, even an iOS or web application would be cool if available.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the whole ruler thing, you can actually find tab sheets; like for instance in [this site](http://www.justinguitar.com/en/PA-000-BlankPaper.php), where there are PDFs with empty guitar tabs for you to print for free:

[image]

There are many different layouts for you available just on that site:

[image]

But also, you can buy these kind of sheet at some music stores. I have seen in guitar shops, but I'm not sure if everyone sells them.